# How to raise ModalBottomSheet height to TopAppBar height?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

There was a small question, how can I raise the bottom sheet contained in the sheetContainter to the height of the TopAppBar, which is in the Scaffold?

My code:

```
Box {
    Scaffold(
        scaffoldState = scaffoldState,
        topBar = {
            TopAppBar(
                title = "text"
            )
        }
    ) { paddingValues ->
       Screen ( ...) 
}
@Composable
Screen (...) {

ModalBottomSheetLayout(
    sheetState = bottomSheetState,
    sheetShape = RoundedCornerShape,
    sheetContent = {
        bottomSheet // here
        )
    },
    content = { ... }
}
```

Comment: @Abhimanyu Replied to you in the comments under your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the requirement is to have a space at the top.

You can use this modifier for the sheet content,

```
val screenHeight = LocalConfiguration.current.screenHeightDp.dp
Modifier.heightIn(
    max = screenHeight - 60.dp,
)
```

You can change the `60.dp` to your `TopAppBar` height.

---

---

If required to Expand when navigating to the screen or opening the app if it is the home screen.

```
val modalBottomSheetState: ModalBottomSheetState = rememberModalBottomSheetState(
    initialValue = ModalBottomSheetValue.Expanded,
    skipHalfExpanded = true,
)
```

Or `initialValue` can be `Hidden` and `modalBottomSheetState.show()` can be used to open the bottom sheet in the expanded state.

Comment: Hello again)
This means that when you conditionally click on some button, you need to open the bottom sheet in height to TopAppBar

Comment: @СергейБеляков Check if the updated answer helps

Comment: Thank you, I'll take a look today and report back.

Comment: Checked - unfortunately, did not help. BottomSheetState opens at the height of the content, but not at the specific height specified in the Modifier.heightIn(
    min = screenHeight - 60.dp,
)

Comment: Thanks, I think I figured out how to do it. In sheetContent, it was actually necessary to set the values the maximum and minimum height, after that it worked. Your tapBar height tip also helped, thanks)

Comment: P.S. Or when you wrote about "Modifier.heightIn( ... )" - did you mean that you need to put it not on the ModalBottomSheet itself, but on its sheetContent?

Comment: Yes, it was for the sheet content. Updated the answer